# how to make the code that runs at 21:00 even though no user opens the application

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Guys can I make a code run at 9:00 p.m. even though no user is opening my application?

I want to give a gift to each user at 21.00, can I put it in my project or I have to create a user like "Admin" who is online to keep my code running at 21.00.

I'm afraid when I enter the code into the project, and when no user opens my application, the prize can't be shared

can anyone give me an idea of ​​its making?

The Clearly question is, i want to push data to database at 21.00 automatic, even though no one has opened my application

Comment: use AlarmManager. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager

Comment: thankyou so much @Rasel

Answer (score 2):

To run your code exactly at 21:00 not even a min. late, use AlarmManager class like this:

```
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            // use setAlarmClock function of AlarmManager
            // but this function will show an alarm icon on statusbar
            // if you dont want to show that icon you can use
            // setExactAndAllowWhileIdle function but that will not be 
            // perfectly exact
        }
        else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            // use setExact function of AlarmManager
        }
        else {
            // use set function of AlarmManager
        }
```

Comment: using alarmmanager means the application will open at the specified time right?, I want it to run without the application having to open, can it?

Comment: @GyrothGames I suggest you do some reading on AlarmManager before trying stuff or guessing. Start here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager

Comment: @GyrothGames no it will not open the app, it will just run the code which you want in background. As Zun suggested plz look into documentation of AlarmManager class or check some basic tutorial on how to use AlarmManager.